# Determining what's causing Facebook to fail loading an image

Tags: html, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I'm setting up various `<meta>` tags to enhance sharing content on my site, particularly the public forums.

So far I've gotten Twitter working perfectly with no effort, but Facebook is being stubborn.

The first issue is that it requires a 200x200 image, so I can't just use the thread creator's avatar since that's 150x150 (and potentially as small as 1x1 if the creator really wants...). So instead I've decided to use a more generic image. I'm not happy with it, but I'd rather that than have it pull a random user's signature image, which is completely irrelevant to the page.

So I set up this tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://pokefarm.com/img/characters/sally_fb.png" />
```

Direct image link: https://pokefarm.com/img/characters/sally_fb.png

The image exists and is over the 200x200 minimum size, but still Facebook's Object Debugger returns the following:

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://img.pokefarm.org/~61/PokeMentors.png' will be used instead.

(And, surprise, the substituted image is completely irrelevant, pulled from a random user's signature, advertising one of their other forum threads.)

I can't find anything wrong with it, but Facebook insists something's wrong. Anyone have any idea what's up?

Comment: Facebook sometimes has problems with images served via HTTPS, so try an HTTP URL if possible. Also, Facebook prefers IPv6 over IPv4, so if you have configured both in DNS settings for the domain, check if the v6 version correctly resolves.

Comment: HTTP doesn't work either, unfortunately. I've put a request to the host to check if IPv6 is configured and, if so, whether it resolves correctly.

Comment: Can you provide an example page/link where you have this og:image tag included?

Comment: The particular page I was trying to get working is this: https://pokefarm.com/forum/thread/24384/Welcome-to-the-Recode